# UPDATE mysql error with Python

Tags: python, mysql

Here's my situation:
I got a table on a database, as following:

```
nome_imagem                       estado     type
57260-tracker-_tracker_face     awake       0
57261-tracker-_tracker_face     drowsiness  1
57268-tracker-_tracker_face     noface      2
57289-tracker-_tracker_face     distracted  3
57290-tracker-_tracker_face     awake       1
57291-tracker-_tracker_face     drowsiness  2
57293-tracker-_tracker_face     noface      3
```

And I want to update de type column according to serveral if conditions, but I'm getting a error on line 29:

> mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

I'm pretty sure its the way im making the query, and I already searched another questions about this before opening this one, but I couldnt solve it anyway.

**EDIT 1:** Changed the query and applied the solution gave by gzc to get rid of the error, but now it updates all the type column instead of just the cases where the if is true

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode
import os

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', database='empresa')
cursor = cnx.cursor()


fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
textDir = os.path.join(fileDir, "test_img")


query = ("SELECT nome_imagem, estado, type FROM alertas ")

cursor.execute(query)
results = list(cursor)

for (nome_imagem, estado, type) in results:
  print nome_imagem, estado

  my_file_name = nome_imagem+'.txt' 
  my_file = open("test_img/"+my_file_name, 'r')
  content = my_file.readline()
  status = content.strip().split()[-1].split("=")[1]
  face = content.strip().split()[0].split("=")[1]
  print status, face #1 tem face, 0 nao tem

  if (face == '1' and estado == status): #se tem cara e o estado que tem na bd for igual ao estado que o programa classificou = correto
    print "correto"
    cursor.execute("UPDATE alertas SET type='1' WHERE nome_imagem=nome_imagem")
  if (face == '1' and estado == 'drowsiness' and status == 'awake') or (face == 1 and estado == 'awake' and status == 'drowsiness'): #verificar isto
    print "trocado"
  if (estado != '' and face == '0'): # se tiver estado mas nao tiver cara classifico logo como errado 3
    print "errado"
  if (estado == 'distracted' and face == '1'): # se tem cara mas for distracted deixo normal pois nao consigo classificar
    print "normal"



cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

**EDIT 2:** gzc solver it again :)

Comment: Is there a stack trace? Which line is the error coming from?

Comment: I don't think you can do two queries at once on the same `cursor`. You better materialize the results of the first query (in a `list`) and then run the second query with the cursor.

Comment: the error is coming from the line 29 "curse.execute("UPDATE ..." @ khelwood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must read all results before doing another operation on the same `cursor`.

```
...
query = ("SELECT nome_imagem, estado, type FROM alertas ")

cursor.execute(query)

results = list(cursor)

for (nome_imagem, estado, type) in results:
...
```

Comment: Yup that was it! But its updating the whole type column and not just the one where the if is true, do you know why? @gzc
Thank you

Comment: Please mark this answer accepted. Try `cursor.execute("UPDATE teste SET type=%s WHERE nome_imagem=%s", ['1', nome_imagem])`.

Comment: the 'something' needs to be the nome_image the for cycle is currently reading, how do I do that? @ gzc

Comment: Perfect! :) Thank you once again @gzc